# How to use Quartz 2D to add drop shadow to an UIImage or UIImageView?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiimageview, uiimage

How do I use Quartz 2D to add drop shadow to an `UIImage` or `UIImageView` ?

Any code samples?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
imageView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
imageView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
imageView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1;
imageView.layer.shadowRadius = 1.0;
```

Don't forget to `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` in your implementation.

**EDIT:**

Adding in @Luke's comment:

Just a little gotcha that might save some other people some time make sure you **have not** set `layer.masksToBounds` to `YES` on your view otherwise the shadow **will not** appear.

Comment: Is the shadow in solid black color ? How to do opaque shadow ? Thanks.

Comment: You set the opacity by modifying the shadowOpacity property.

Comment: I did it all and the error is: "Property 'layer' not found on object of type 'UIImage'", what should I do?

Comment: @ValKalinic Ensure the QuartzCore Framework is added to your XCode project.

Comment: Just a little gotcha that might save some other people some time make sure you haven't set masksToBounds to YES on your view otherwise the shadow won't appear!

layer.masksToBounds = YES;

Answer (score 1):

```
+ (void)addShadowToView:(UIView*)view Color:(UIColor*)color ShadowOffset:(CGSize)offset Radius:(float)radius Opacity:(float)opacity
{
    view.layer.shadowColor = [color CGColor];
    view.layer.shadowOffset = offset;
    view.layer.shadowRadius = radius;
    view.layer.shadowOpacity = opacity;
}
```

Use:

```
[calssName addShadowToView:self.navigationController.navigationBar Color:[UIColor blackColor] ShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(1.0f, 0.5f) Radius:1.0 Opacity:0.5];
```