# Objective C: How to add Shadow effect to navigation bar and table cells

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uinavigationbar, shadow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use Quartz 2D to add drop shadow to an UIImage or UIImageView ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973298/how-to-use-quartz-2d-to-add-drop-shadow-to-an-uiimage-or-uiimageview)

Hi,

I have created a tableViewController and want to try to add the shadow effect for both the navigation bar as well as the table cells. Can anyone guide me on the approach to do so?

Thanks!

Zhen Hoe

Answer (score 44, accepted):

try this

```
yourView.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
yourView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1.0f, 1.0f);
yourView.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0f;
yourView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0f;
```

You'll need to replace "yourView" with nav bar or table cell

Btw, also you'll need import QuartzCore/CALayer.h

Comment: With no reference but only as a caution, please do not use this in any scroll view. For example, using it in a table view cell just destroys the scrolling smoothness. But if you need it on a non movable view, works like a charm

Comment: If you want to use it with tableview you can create UIView and add UITableView into that UIView and make shadow on UIView layer will solve smoothness problem. (PS. I didn't try with UIScrollView)