# Is there a way to add a "glow" effect to the title text in my Navigation Bar? (xcode 4.2, iOS 5.0)

Tags: ios4, ios5, xcode4.2

I was wondering if there was a way in xcode to make a "glow" effect for my text (a border around the text in a different color).  Is this possible and if so how is it done?  Please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013137/objective-c-how-to-add-shadow-effect-to-navigation-bar-and-table-cells

Comment: This is not a duplicate...the solution in the link in question did not work.    I have a background image for my navigation bar, then the text over top.  The layer.shadow color does not work in this case.  Please help with a solution.

Comment: I do not want just a "shadow" effect, I would like the entire text to be wrapped in the glow

Answer (score 0):

You can use image and edit the titleView or you can use some kind of a font that has glow ... to display, you can use https://github.com/FuerteInternational/FTCoreText (of course this would require to replace the titleView as well) ...

To replace titleView do something like this: [self.navigationItem setTitleView:yourView];