# Shadows in UITableView are not consistent

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview

I am adding `shadows` to individual cells of a `UITableView`. The shadows are not consistent in the sense, please consider the following scenario:

There are 20 rows to show and initially, on the first view only 10 are visible. Here shadows are visible properly as expected. But as soon as I scroll down/up, some of the new cells visible now, are showing shadows as expected while others are not. The issue looks to be with the `zPosition` of the `UITableViewCell`'s `layer`. For some cells the shadow is behind while for others it is in front as compared to the cell lying underneath it which makes it visible/invisible to the user.

Since, most of the posts I encountered (for eg. [Objective C: How to add Shadow effect to navigation bar and table cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013137/objective-c-how-to-add-shadow-effect-to-navigation-bar-and-table-cells)) does not set the `UITableViewCell`'s layer's zPosition explicitly so I wanted to know whether that is required or there is something I am missing here.

Edit: Please find the code snippets here

```
    -(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
       navigatorCell* cell = (navigatorCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"] forIndexPath:indexPath];


    // cell configuration code goes here

   //now add shadow     
       [cell.layer setMasksToBounds:NO];
       cell.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
       cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 5.0f);
       cell.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0f;
       cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.750f;
       cell.clipsToBounds = NO;
      //if I uncomment this, then it works properly, but problem arises again if I insert/remove cells
      // cell.layer.zPosition = -indexpath.row; 

       CGRect shadowFrame = cell.layer.bounds;
       CGPathRef shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:shadowFrame].CGpath;
       cell.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath;
       return cell;
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the screen shot......

Comment: Can you please add your code. without code i can't do any thing

Comment: pleaes find the code above.

Answer (score 0):

try like this may be it works,

```
    -(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
   navigatorCell* cell = (navigatorCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

             if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

            // cell configuration code goes here

           //now add shadow     
               [cell.layer setMasksToBounds:NO];
               cell.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
               cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 5.0f);
               cell.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0f;
               cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.750f;
               cell.clipsToBounds = NO;
              //if I uncomment this, then it works properly, but problem arises again if I insert/remove cells
              // cell.layer.zPosition = -indexpath.row; 

               CGRect shadowFrame = cell.layer.bounds;
               CGPathRef shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:shadowFrame].CGpath;
               cell.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath;
              }
               return cell;
            }
```